# Deploy war to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, war

How to deploy war file into AWS(Amezon Web Services),
please kindly provide me some guide to do this..
urget one.

Windows 7(64-bit)

Thanks & Regards,
Muthu

Comment: You should give details about platform too - Linux/Window?

Answer (score 3):

You can deploy your war file using Elastic Bean Stalk which is a Platform as a Service Offering of AWS. It helps you to create a stack i.e. a compute platform with all required softwares (App Server, RDS, Web Server, Install Softwares etc).

If you already have an AWS environment present or an instance running, you can use AWS Code Deploy

[Code Deploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a ec2-instance, You can paste your war file in var/lib/tomcat/webapps folder. The tomcat will automatically deploy the project and then you can access it from your browser. If it does not deploy automatically then you have to set autodeploy=true.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for what tool to use or steps?
I would add the server to the IDE and use it to build/run against. This should be available for NetBeans and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are connecting to windows instance.

Connect to your EC2 Instance using RDP.
Download and Install Tomcat.
Configure the server.xml, tomcat-users and set the username, password and port.

Once done,
you can place your war file in the /webapps folder.
or
Open your instance's Public IP in url. Login to the tomcats management using the username and password you have set.
browse and deploy the war file.

Start the applications shown in the list.

Your App is ready.

Hope it helps.. :)